# WYSIWYG editor is not selecting the image name

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg

Selecting from thumbnail not showing the complete path of image. It is insert below

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/"}}" alt="" />
```

I tried everything but cannot solved this issue. Thumbnail are showing and uploader work too.

Anyone face the similar issue?

**Magento ver. 1.9.3.2**

Comment: ajax call goes to admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/onInsert with the base64_encode file name of the image as `filename` parameter. Make sure each Thumbnail div has that id

Comment: @GopalPatel yes it has the id and same goes for post `dGVzdGluZy5qcGVn`.

Comment: check  $filename variable in `getImageHtmlDeclaration` function `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php`

Comment: @GopalPatel its seem to me `base64_decode($string);` not working

Comment: Not sure may be php version issue